# Undefined js functions when pushing to heroku, working fine on local

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've just pushed my app to heroku, and those JS calls made with  in the view, are not working, giving me several errors like:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerHelper' of undefined
(index):456 Uncaught ReferenceError: drawStaticPin is not defined
application-d6ce5af7abb100d97c6fb3d389a27fba.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(index):346 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I've tried to put defer="defer", but they still wont work.

It's like if the  tags are rendering before the assets/js path.

**EDIT**

My js is loaded in application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.lockfixed
//= require jquery.base64
//= require jquery.browser.mobile
//= require helpers/masonry_helper
//= require_directory ./utils
//= require_directory ./helpers
//= require tabs
//= require pining
//= require list
//= require handlebars
//= require jquery.cookiesdirective
//= require albums
//= require landing
//= require bxslider
//= require landing/waypoints
//= require landing/animate-waypoints
//= require handlebars-truncate-helper
//= require masonry.pkgd.min
//= require spots
```

And I have several calls in views as:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
        $(function() {
          <% photo.pins.limit(1).each do |pin| %>
            drawPin(<%= pin.to_json.html_safe %>);
          <% end %>
        });
    </script>
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Seeing how you load the JS in your app, and where you are calling these functions would be handy.

Comment: How and where is `drawPin` defined?

Comment: in pining.js which is loaded in application.html.erb. It's defined correctly, the problem comes only in production